# Find the coefficient of a negative indexed $x$ in a series expansion

Tags: binomial-coefficients, binomial-theorem

```
Find the coefficient of x-10 in the expansion:
(2-1/x2)8
```

```
ANS: -448
```

I've tried using the General Term formula and got stuck at *-x<sup>2r</sup> = x<sup>-10</sup>*. Also, I tried expanding the equation but it doesn't look like its leading me somewhere.

Comment: It's the same as the coefficient of $y^5$ in $(2-y)^8$.

Comment: *Mathematica* gives:  $\frac{1}{x^{16}}-\frac{16}{x^{14}}+\frac{112}{x^{12}}-\frac{448}{x^{10}}+\frac{1120}{x^8}-\frac{1792}{x^6}+\frac{1792}{x
   ^4}-\frac{1024}{x^2}+256+O\left(x^6\right)$.

Comment: @DavidG.Stork, the answer is 21/2..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've got the right idea.  We know $$(a+b)^8=\sum_{k=0}^{8}{8\choose k}a^{8-k}b^k$$ so we just need to see what happens when $a=2, b=-x^{-2}.$  If order to get the $x^{-10}$ term, we need $k=5$ since $(x^{-2})^5=x^{10}.$  Then the coefficient will be $${8\choose5}2^{8-5}(-1)^5=-8\cdot56=-448$$

Comment: I guess the answer to the exercise is wrong, the right answer is -448 then.

Comment: @BenAvelson It certainly looks that way.  Three different people have computed $-448.$

Comment: you are right, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You have eight factors of $(2-\frac 1{x^2})$  You need to choose $5$ of them to supply $\frac 1{x^2}$ to get the right power of $x$, so $3$ of them give a $2$.  There are ${8 \choose 5}=56$ ways to choose the five and the three factors of $2$ give a factor $8$.  The answer is $$-56 \cdot 8=-448$$

Comment: I guess the answer to the exercise is wrong, the right answer is -448 then.